# rc.local doesn't run on startup

Tags: 14.04, scripts, startup

I know this question has been asked a lot of times already, and I think I might have tried everything suggested on the internet, but I just can't get it running

/etc/rc.local:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

while :
do

    alsactl restore
    if [ $? = 0 ]
    then
        echo "alsactl restored" >> ~/Desktop/rc.log
        break
    else
        echo $?
    fi
    sleep 2

done

exit 0
```

permissions are

```
$ ls -l /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 855 Jul   5 17:05 /etc/rc.local
```

any ideas?

Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You need to add `exit 0` at the end of the `/etc/rc.local` file..run this  `sudo bash -c 'echo "exit 0" >>/etc/rc.local'`

Comment: oh, yes, it is there already, my bad - didn't copy it to the end. fixed the question

Comment: Does `/root/Desktop` exist? If not, the script will error out either way since you have `-e` on the shebang.

Comment: You need to have the full path to all commands since `rc.local` is run before `$PATH` is set